# Lombok @Log4j2 annotation doesn't work in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2, lombok

I'm using Lombok library in my project and have a problem with `@Log4j2` annotation. Not sure why but it's not generating `log` field in the `class`.

But when I'm changing annotation to `@Slf4j` it works, I can see it in IntelliJ IDEA 'Structure' tab.

I'm using `gradle` as a build tool. Have few dependencies"

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
}
```

Comment: Please, show your logger dependencies

Comment: @Serghey I can see next dependencies https://snag.gy/7fDA6y.jpg

Comment: Actually log4j2 works through Slf4j, because it uses log4j2.xml configs. Just wondering why annotation is not working

Comment: It could be that the IDEA plug-in doesn't support @Log4j2 yet. If that's the case IDEA will show an error message, but compiling the code should work.

Comment: @ChirrutImwe it's not

Comment: This option works for me:
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'

}

Answer (score 9):

So I had the same problem, I think. What I did is I installed the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ, enabled the annotation as in the link under Preferences-> Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors. And then I restarted IntelliJ, and it worked. IDE is able to recognize log.

I tried it for log4j, log4j2 and slf4j. It all worked.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I am on IntelliJ Idea 2020.2 Mac Version with lombok plugin 0.32-2020.2. In addition to the above answer I also had to turn on log annotation in lombok plugin settings (Preferences > Other Settings > Lombok Plugin > Enable @Log support)

Answer (score 3):

Just installing the lombok plugin for intellij works for me.